# Replace all line breaks with \n and tabulations with \t in a XML string by powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, non-ascii-characters

I have an XML string like this one:

```
<store:book name="history">
  <department>one</department>
  <department>two</department>
</store:book>
```

I would need to change it as follows, because I need to pass it as parameter to a REST web service, having a JSON body:

```
<store:book name="history">\n\t<department>one</department>\n\t<department>two</department>\n</store:book>
```

How can I do it by powershell?

Note that the string comes after reading the content of a file as:

```
$updatedSource = Get-Content $file -Raw
```

EDIT: to better clarify my requirement I would need to fill the JSON parameter like this:

```
$postData = "{""Source"":""${updatedSource}""}"
```

EDIT: Adding target REST call. The code for the request is already correct, I tested it with a string populated as the target would be...

```js
[System.Net.HttpWebRequest] $req = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest] [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($finalUri)
$req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + $toolingService.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId)
$req.ContentType = "application/json"
$req.Method = "PATCH"

$postData = "{""Source"":""${updatedSource}""}"
$encodedContent = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($postData)

$req.ContentLength = $encodedContent.length
$requestStream = $req.GetRequestStream()
$requestStream.Write($encodedContent, 0, $encodedContent.length)
$requestStream.Close()

[System.Net.WebResponse] $res =  $req.GetResponse()
[System.IO.StreamReader] $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($res.GetResponseStream(), [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
$result = $reader.ReadToEnd()

$serializer = New-Object -TypeName System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$obj = $serializer.DeserializeObject($result)
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused... does the REST service not handle whitespace in the request object properly? That surprises me.

Comment: Also you mention a JSON body... none of what you've posted looks like JSON to me! Are we missing some information?

Comment: I have updated my requirement above. The point is the JSON parameter does not allow line breaks into string value therefore I have to escape them with both \n and \t

Comment: There is still no json. It's xml.

Comment: How are you making the API call?

Comment: Added REST call above. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved as follows:

Replaced this code:

```html
$updatedSource = Get-Content $file -Raw
```

with:

```html
$updatedSource = Get-Content $file
$updatedSource = $updatedSource -join '\n'
$updatedSource = $updatedSource.replace("""","\""")
```

The tabulations themselves are definitely not an issue since they are accepted as JSON value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Replace function:

```
$updatedSource = $updatedSource.Replace("`n","\n").Replace("`t","\t")
```

note that the escape character is a backtick, not an apostrophe.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer! Getting some weird output after trying this solution:

\n</store:book>>two</department>